# How Copy sqlite db From externalsd download folder To internal personal folder

Tags: xamarin, copy

i have a code to copy my sqlite database to external download folder.and it was worked.
now i have this backup.how to restore it.means copy back to pesonal folder.

my code is:

```
Java.IO.File dbFile = new Java.IO.File(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "netfilingAutomation"));

var des = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString();


File.Copy(dbFile.ToString(), des, true);

Toast.MakeText(this, "backup success", ToastLength.Long).Show();  `
}
```

i want reverse destination and source but i cant.i have read write permission.

Comment: what does "but I can't" mean?  Do you get an error, an exception, or what?  What is the specific problem?

Comment: i get Permission Error.when read download folder.but in my manifest i set read write permission.and in my installed app setting i turn on read write permissions.but i get this error only when reverse this code to copy (means Restore) to my app personal folder.and when copy (backup) from personal to download folder,every things ok.

Comment: no body helping